# Single Inheritance C++ and header files

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm getting an

```
expected class-name before '{' token
```

in the following code

the saltwaterfish.h header file:

```
#ifndef SALTWATERFISH_H
#define SALTWATERFISH_H


class saltwaterfish: public fish
{
public:
    saltwaterfish();
    float GetUnitPrice();
    float GetWeight();
};

#endif // SALTWATERFISH_H
```

Is this the correct way to define the header file for

"saltwaterfish is a subclass of fish" ?

the only thing I have in saltwaterfish.cpp is

```
#include "fish.h"
#include "saltwaterfish.h"
```

the fish.cpp class:

```
#include "fish.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "freshwaterfish.h"
#include "saltwaterfish.h"

using namespace std;

fish::fish()
{
};

float fish::CalculatePrice()
{
    return GetUnitPrice()*GetWeight();
}

float fish::GetUnitPrice()
{
    return 1.0;
}

float fish::GetWeight()
{
    return 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post code for fish class here.Probably you are missing `};` at the end of fish class.

Comment: Are you getting this error for `saltwaterfish.cpp`?

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the body of the `fish` constructor.

Comment: Your header file is not self-contained. fish is not defined at that point your your header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the `fish.h` header file in saltwaterfish.h

```
//saltwaterfish.h
#include"fish.h"
#ifndef SALTWATERFISH_H
#define SALTWATERFISH_H


class saltwaterfish: public fish
{
public:
    saltwaterfish();
    float GetUnitPrice();
    float GetWeight();
};
#endif // SALTWATERFISH_H
```

The compiler does not see that Fish is a class, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should put

```
#include "fish.h"
```

in the header file itself. (saltwaterfish.h)

Otherwise this code won't have access to fish class.

Good luck.

Comment: Doesn't explain the problem though (unless it's in a different source file, not mentioned in the question).

Comment: `#ifndef SALTWATERFISH_H` at the top of the code suggests that this code is in saltwaterfish.h

Comment: @TanmayPatil is there a difference between putting `"fish.h"` and `<fish.h>` ?

Comment: Yes. <fish.h> means that the compiler will search in all include directories. On the other hand, "fish.h" will make the compiler search in the sources as well.

Comment: Although this is compiler implementation dependent, more on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Answer (score 0):

The error means "the thing before the { is supposed to be a class name, but it's not." So 'fish' is not a class name. Look for the declaration of the fish class, and make sure it's loaded before this declaration.