# First Post! Error using inheritance with header files

Tags: c++, inheritance, header

this is my first post here on stack overflow! I have used this website for years and I appreciate all of the help and time invested by everyone. It has been priceless in helping me write good code.

I get the following error message when I try to compile: "error: expected class name". I have searched the internet and I have been unsuccessful in finding a solution to my problem. I also went to "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm" and "[Single Inheritance C++ and header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496468/single-inheritance-c-and-header-files)" for help with inheritance and using header files. But still my problem persists and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have trimmed my code down to the bare bones and presented it below. Your help would be much appreciated.

Compiler

```
$ make
c++    -c -o RectangleClass.o RectangleClass.cpp
c++    -c -o ShapeClass.o ShapeClass.cpp
In file included from ShapeClass.cpp:1:
In file included from ./ShapeClass.h:4:
./RectangleClass.h:6:26: error: expected class name
class Rectangle : public Shape {
                     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [ShapeClass.o] Error 1
```

makefile

```
lab8: RectangleClass.o ShapeClass.o main.o
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra

main.o: main.cpp
RectangleClass.o: RectangleClass.h
ShapeClass.o: ShapeClass.h

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.o
    $(RM) main RectangleClass ShapeClass lab8
    $(RM) *~
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ShapeClass.h"

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

ShapeClass.h which is the parent class

```
#ifndef SHAPECLASS_H
#define SHAPECLASS_H

#include "RectangleClass.h"

class Shape {
 private:
  double area;

 public:
  Shape(double defaultArea = 0);

};

#endif
```

ShapeClass.cpp

```
#include "ShapeClass.h"

Shape::Shape (double inputArea) {
  area   = inputArea;
}
```

RectangleClass.h which is the derived class

```
#ifndef RECTANGLECLASS_H
#define RECTANGLECLASS_H

#include "ShapeClass.h"

class Rectangle : public Shape {
};

#endif
```

RectangleClass.cpp

```
#include "RectangleClass.h"
```

Comment: Why does ShapeClass.h include `RectangleClass.h`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (erroneously) #include "RectangleClass.h" inside ShapeClass.h.

At that point Shape is not defined yet and the RectangleClass class definition tries to inherit from something that is not yet defined. Thus the error.